# Uncaught ImagickException: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF'

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to readImage() using Imagick but somehow I am constantly getting the error above. I even amended the policy.xml as suggested by other posts and restarted apache. This is how it looks like. Is there anything I am missing out?

```
 <policymap>
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="shred" value="2"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="memory-map" value="anonymous"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="max-memory-request" value="256MiB"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="512MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="list-length" value="128"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="1GiB"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" /> 
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" /> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" /> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="cache" name="memory-map" value="anonymous"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="cache" name="synchronize" value="True"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="pixel-cache-memory" value="anonymous"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="shred" value="2"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- use curl -->
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="read|write" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="read|write" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="read|write" pattern="HTTP" />
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="read|write" pattern="@*"/>
  <!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS2" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS3" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="XPS" />
</policymap>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just had same error fixed it by installing ghost script 9.5 and restart php with the command

(on nginx)
sudo systemctl restart php8.0-fpm
(on apache)

sudo systemctl restart apache2

make sure to change your php version if you are using nginx